# Firebase Query to search one level deep nodes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on the search feature for my App. My Database has a list of products. I want to find the product name with my Query.

The below code works for single category.

```
Query searchRef = mProdDB.child("c01").orderByChild("productName").startAt(searchString);

for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          Product Prod = Product.create(resultSnapshot);
          mProd.add(Prod);
}
```

[image: Schema]

1. The problem is that the products are inside each category node like `c01`. But I want to search all the categories. How can I do that ?
2. In the screenshot, `c08p10` is followed by `c08p102`. How can i sort the products with the `productID` ?

**UPDATE**

In my case, I have over 1000 products in each category.

APPROACH 1:

Adding all the products under the `Products` node & have a attribute called `CategoryID` in each Product.

Comment: Try to iterate over your `Products` first and store the keys of the categories. Then use your working code from the top, but instead of `"c01"` you will use each of the keys collected before. If you can, I would suggest to redesign your data structure. To increase performance you should avoid such nested structures.

Comment: If I have all the products under a single parents `Products`. How can i filter the `productID` that startswith `c01` ?

Comment: If all your products only have one category (like in your example) you could create an attribute `category` for every product and set it to your specific category. Then you can filter by this attribute. To answer your second question about the sorting of your products by id: They are already sorted. Since keys are stored as strings, a string, that is a prefix of another, will always be first. Therefore 'p10' -> 'p101' -> 'p102'

Comment: What will be the best way, If each category has over 500 products ?

Comment: That can't be answered without knowing what your current (or future) use cases are. You should check out the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) and maybe [this article](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data) to get a better understanding of data modelling for Firebase. Depending on your use cases, there might not even be THE best approach, but they will help you deduce a good approach for your needs.